# MultiArray login system

Tags: php, html, login-script

I'm trying to create multi array login system with, but only the first account is working correctly. The other 2 show wrong password/name
1 is Name, 2 is login nickname and 3 is password.

```
<?php
$names=array(
1=>[
    1=>'test',
    2=>'test',
    3=>test
],
2=>[
    1=>'test1',
    2=>'test1',
    3=>'test1'
],
3=>[
    1=>'test2',
    2=>'test2',
    3=>'test2'
]
);
foreach($names as $number)
if($_POST){
    if($_POST['user']==$number[2] && $_POST['pass']==$number[3]){
        echo 'Welcome, ' . $number[1];
        break;
    }
    else{
        echo 'Wrong Username/Password. Please, try again!';
        break;
    }
}
?>
```

Comment: Your `else` statement is exiting the loop as soon as a non-match is encountered, so it will never get past the first record in `$names`. You need to remove the `else` statement.

Comment: Also, `$names[1][3]` is a constant which will be converted to a string. You should wrap it in quotes.

Answer (score 1):

When the loop goes to `else`  the loop will `break` and stops searching, if you remove the break it will keep echoing `wrong/username password` until the user is found. you can do it like this

```
$login = false;
foreach($names as $number){
    if($_POST){
        if($_POST['user']==$number[2] && $_POST['pass']==$number[3]){
            echo 'Welcome, ' . $number[1];
            $login = true;
            break;
        }
    }
}

if(!$login)
{
    echo 'wrong username/password';
}
```

Answer (score 1):

from the part of your loop edit your code to look like code below 
.

```js
$i=0; // added value to loop for post values too, assume input boxes for username and password are consecutive
foreach($names as $number)
if($_POST){
    if($_POST['user'][$i] == $number[2] && $_POST['pass'][$i] == $number[3]){
        echo 'Welcome, ' . $number[1];
        break;
    }
    else{
        echo "Wrong Username/Password. $number[1] Please , try again!";
        

    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Or using return value like this:

```
function checkUser($names) {
  foreach($names as $number) {
     if($_POST['user']==$number[2] && $_POST['pass']==$number[3])
        return 'Welcome, ' . $number[1];       
  }
  return 'Wrong Username/Password. Please, try again!';
}
if ($_POST) echo checkUser($names);
```

Answer (score 0):

I do it the easy way. Thanks to @Simon MᶜKenzie for the idea:

```
$i=1337;
foreach($names as $number)
if($_POST){
    if($_POST['user']==$number[2] && $_POST['pass']==$number[3]){
        echo 'Welcome, ' . $number[1] . '!';
        $i=1;
        break;
    }else{
    $i=0;
    }
}
if($i==0){
    echo 'Wrong Username/Password. Please, try again!';
}
```